# Livecode: place an image over another image at runtime

Tags: livecode

Livecode 9.0 question:
I want to place a smaller image from one substack over a larger image from another substack on the main stack at runtime. I've tried several approaches to the code, but to no avail. For example, set the ink of card to blendSrc just doesn't work, as well as all the other blend params. Can someone pass the code to me for this routine, please? How is it done at runtime?

TIA,

John

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are thinking of blend stuff. Your question asks how to place one image over another.

You can simply (pseudo):

```
copy img 1 of stack yourSubstack1 to stack "yourTargetStack"
copy img 2 of stack yourSubstack2 to stack "yourTargetStack"
set the loc of img 2 of stack "yourTargetStack" to locOfYourChoice
```

This obviates the need to actually navigate to the target stack, though you are welcome to do so, and may actually want to.

After that, you can experiment with gadgetry such as blendLevels (set the blendLevel of img 1 to 50)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[relayer](https://livecode.com/resources/api/#livecode_script/relayer)** command

```
on mouseUp
    relayer image "Image1" after button "Image2"
 end mouseUp
```